# How do I customize PuTTy color output & text options in the shortcut/startup?

Tags: putty, application-settings

PuTTy always limits the window size, scroll history and colors whenever I open it up by default.  I like to save copies of what I do in PuTTy because I'm still learning, but if I've done too much work I lose everything I did before 500 lines if I forgot to change it.  Is there a way to tell PuTTy to open with the "Lines of Scrollback" setting at 10000, and window size, etc?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Change the settings, and then save it as a session.

Comment: Thanks Oli for being so helpful.  I was thinking along the lines of adding parameters to the exe - do you know of anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to save a server connection as a profile, and when you make changes to the scrollback and colours, you need to go back to the profiles list and save there.  If you save without going back to that profiles screen, in my experience it won't save.

Comment: Thanks Mick that was helpful.  What do you think about possibly adding just the rows, columns, and scrollback settings as parameters to the exe file?  ie. putty.exe -columns 237 -rows 63 -lines 50000?  Do you think something like this could work that way any session I choose to open (new or old) will have these settings?